# Comunication with Timeline with button in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to find some way how to branch Timeline and play this branch after you select one of two options with button. But I did not find it.

> Example: You have two different paths (right path and left path). You
> click on right button for select right path it will trigger part of
> timeline or new timeline. Or you can click on left button for select
> left path...

Can this be done by signal emitters? And I need for this more then 1 timeline or I can branch timeline and select one of the branches? Have somebody experience with this if statement in Timeline?

I need just hint how to do this or it is possible at all. :D Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script-free method would be to play the primary timeline and have an activation track that activates a parent GameObject that has two or more GameObjects as children, which in turn have their own PlayableDirector-Components with the "Play on Awake" option checked. These child GameObjects are initially disabled and depending on the branch or button click, you activate the selected GameObject and you have a branch to other timelines without the need for a script.

With scripting there is an option to mute tracks, for which the playable graph has to be recreated, and as far as I know you also have to search the tracks by name, so you have to rename the tracks and do a somewhat vulnerable string comparison. But that works as well and it can be done with one timeline.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's possible. I don't know exactly how you want it to run but let's say you branch and freeze everything in place and instantiate/copy everything to run in place of the original copies. Then when a condition is met like a button or a timer you can destroy everything that was copied and unfreeze the originals for a rewind kind of effect. There's probably a bunch of different ways you can do it but that's what I can think of off the top of my head.